# Problema con Codeigniter Error:Type: ArgumentCountError

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

Estoy utilizando Codeignter y tengo el siguiente error:

> Message: Too few arguments to function CtrlPdfPrueba::index(), 0
>   passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\bioanestesys\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on
>   line 532 and exactly 3 expected
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bioanestesys\application\controllers\Trans\CtrlPdfPrueba.php
>
> Line Number: 11

Comment: Explica mas la pregunta

Comment: Lo que dice el error es que la función `index` recibe 3 parámetros y tu no le estas enviando ninguno.

Comment: Hasta ese punto creo que si lo entiendo ... El problema es que no se donde estoy haciendo mal las cosas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es por que **no se pueden asignar parámetros a la función `index()`en un controlador de Codeigniter**. Una solución simple es crear otra función con otro nombre y dejar el index en blanco o utilizar variables de sesión (que es lo mas recomendable) en lugar de pasar datos como el id del paciente como parámetros por la url (lo cual es una malisima practica que hace el sistema vulnerable a Inyección SQL).

La solución rápida (pero no recomendable) es la siguiente:

```
    <?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CtrlPdfPrueba extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index(){

    }
    public function paciente($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo){

        if($this->session->userdata('nombre') != NULL){
            $idpaciente = base64_decode(urldecode($idpaciente));
            $id = base64_decode(urldecode($id));
            $data = array(
            'paciente'=>$idpaciente,
            'cirugia'=>$id,
            'tiempo'=>$tiempo,
            'query2'=>$this->modPreIdPaciente->informacionDetallePaciente($idpaciente,$id),
            'queryFC'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloFC($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPulso'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPulso($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPAS'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPAS($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPAD'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPAD($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPAM'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPAM($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'querySpO2'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloSpO2($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryEtCO2'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloEtCO2($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryTemp1'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloTemp1($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryTemp2'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloTemp2($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryBIS_L'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloBIS_L($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryBIS_R'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloBIS_R($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPVC'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPVC($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPAS_In'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPAS_In($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPAD_In'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPAD_In($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPAM_In'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPAM_In($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPIC'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPIC($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryCAM'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloCAM($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryFiO2'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloFiO2($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryFiCO2'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloFiCO2($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryFiIso'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloFiSo($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryFiN2O'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloFiN2O($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryEtIso'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloEtIso($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryEtN2O'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloEtN2O($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryEtO2'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloEtO2($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryFR'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloFR($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo),
            'queryPAP'=>$this->ModPdfPrueba->buscaintervaloPAP($idpaciente,$id,$tiempo)
            );

            $this->load->view('Panel/Trans/reporte_pdf',$data);

        }
        else{
                redirect('CtrlPrincipal');
            }
    }
}
```

De esta forma ya solo debes agregar `paciente`a tu URL para ingresar. Aun así por seguridad investiga sobre como usar variables de sesión. Espero te sea de ayuda y revisa mas documentación de Codeigniter. Saludos.

Comment: de nada @mary, indícame si necesitas algo.